# HotTowel: Viewmodel lose mapping when navigating between pages

Tags: knockout-mapping-plugin, single-page-application, hottowel

I just started with HotTowel and very impressed. I manage to learn how to use it with knockout binding.
Here's the problem I'm facing:

I have a website with 3 pages: Home, About, Jar

In Jar I have:

```
define(['services/logger', 'repo/jarrepo'], function (logger, repo) {
    var Jar = function () {
        this.Id = ko.observable(0);
        this.Name = ko.observable('');        
    }

    this.jars = ko.mapping.fromJS([]);

    var vm = {
        title: ko.observable('JARS'),
        jars: jars,
        AddJar: function () {
            this.jars.push(new Jar);
        },
        DeleteJar: function (jar) {
            jars.destroy(jar);
        },
        activate: function () {
            repo.getJars(this.jars);
            return true;
        }
    };

    return vm;
});
```

And in the view I have:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: jars">
    <label data-bind="text: name" />
    <a href="#" data-bind="click $root.DeleteJar">Delete</a>
</div>
```

My repo code:

```
$.getJSON("/api/jar/getjars", function (data) {
            ko.mapping.fromJS(data, jars);
        });
```

It works fine if I'm on Jar page. However, when I navigate to Home and come back, the ko mapping is lost. I check it by using chrome console and check for the the jars array and all of its elements has lost the `ko.mapping` node in the attribute. Thus I cannot delete the jar but can still add new one to it.

Can anyone help me figure out how to remap the object after navigation? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Your repo.getJars(this.jars); is an asyncronous task, so you must return a promise in your activate function to things work properly.

I Think that this will do the trick:

```
activate: function () {
        return repo.getJars(this.jars);
    }
```

Your repo should also return the promise:

```
function getJars(jars){
    return $.getJson(...);
}
```

Comment: What would you do if you needed to do stuff in the activate method after the data was loaded?

Comment: I'll do something like:      var promise = $.Deferred();

    someStuff().then(function(){
 promise.resolve();
    }).fail(function(){
 promise.reject();
    });

    return promise;