# Race condition during Durandal bind - no promise required

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, durandal

There is an apparent race condition in Durandal around the page composition/binding.

Questions have been asked about this before on Stackoverflow, but the answers given (which were accepted) seem to be glossing over an underlying race condition that I think will continue to catch people out.

The problem is as described here:
[Durandal KO Binding View Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15415436/durandal-ko-binding-view-issue)

This is the code in question:

```
define(function (require) {
var http = require('durandal/http');

return {
    subjectItem: function (data) {
        var self = this;
        self.Subject_ID = data.Subject_ID;
        self.Subject_Name = data.Subject_Name;
    },
    subjects: ko.observableArray([]),
    activate: function () {
        var self = this;
        http.ajaxRequest("get", "/api/values/getsubjects")
            .done(function (allData) {
                var mappedSubjects = $.map(allData, function (list) { return new self.subjectItem(list); });
                self.subjects(mappedSubjects);
            });
    }
};
});
```

The answer given to this question has been that the activate function should have returned the result of the ajax call, which is a promise. This would cause Durandal to wait for the ajax call to complete before continuing to the binding stage.

The problem with that answer is that there should be no reason to wait for the ajax call to complete. The viewmodel above already contains an empty observableArray which should successfully bind to the template with or without any elements. If and when the ajax call completes, the new data added to the observableArray will be added to the page.

This can be proved as follows. Instead of firing off the ajax call at the same time as proceeding to the bind, use a setTimeout to trigger the ajax call after binding has completed. When you do this, the race condition is avoided, and the page works every time.

This is the modified code:

```
define(function (require) {
var http = require('durandal/http');

return {
    subjectItem: function (data) {
        var self = this;
        self.Subject_ID = data.Subject_ID;
        self.Subject_Name = data.Subject_Name;
    },
    subjects: ko.observableArray([]),
    activate: function () {
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(function () {
          http.ajaxRequest("get", "/api/values/getsubjects")
              .done(function (allData) {
                  var mappedSubjects = $.map(allData, function (list) { return new self.subjectItem(list); });
                  self.subjects(mappedSubjects);
              });
        },1500);
    }
};
});
```

It is only when the observableArray is updated during page binding that the page breaks. This is something that could happen at any time (seemingly at random) if a setInterval is running in the background regularly refreshing a long-lived observableArray.

So my question is, if this isn't a race condition within Durandal, why do we get seemingly random breakages when observableArrays are updated asynchronously and simultaneous with page binds, but no breakages when the observableArray is updated after binding is complete?

Update:
I found a really simple way to trigger this problem. Assuming you've got an observableArray in your viewmodel accessible as "firewallList" (I do), this will trigger the problem:

```
function activate() {
    var counter=0;
    var timer=setInterval(function() {
        counter++;
        if(counter > 20) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            return;
        }
        firewallList.push(new Firewall({id: counter, name: 'item'+counter, description: 'description'+counter}));
    }, 10);

}
```

I get different results depending on how I vary the interval value. When it's 10ms I end up getting one row displayed in the table. If I drop that to 7ms, I get either one or two rows in my table. The subsequent objects do get added to the observableArray, but never make it to the DOM. Once this problem is triggered, No amount of manipulation of the observableArray will cause any update to the DOM.

Comment: I'm not sure your evidence indicates that this is *not* an issue with Durandal.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is an issue with Durandal, but the normal advice that people with this problem are given is that the problem is with their code. I'm really hoping that the very knowledgable people here can cast more light on the issue.

Comment: I'm using Durandal 1.2. I think I've found the answer to my question here:
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/durandaljs/AQZ9XH_6FNE/kwwoOTRr-soJ

Comment: Reading between the lines, it does sound like race condition in Durandal 1.2 that has been eliminated in Durandal 2.0. The fact that the Durandal people have "fixed" this would suggest that it was not a knockout bug.